# How do I ungroup the children from parents

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I am a beginner at blender, and I've been trying to separate the Children from the parents

Comment: You can clear parent/child relationships by selecting both objects and pressing Alt+P

Comment: There's not enough information to help you with the "where some of the shape meshes I've inserted" part. You might do better to edit this one to just clearing parents, and create a separate question for the second part, they don't seem to be related.

Comment: Thanks for telling me by doing Alt+P.

Answer (score 2):

Select the child object and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd>, then *Clear Parent* (also available from the *Object* menu.

Documentation is here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html#clear-parent